# A to Z list of char from Enumerable.Range

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I want to make a list from Enumerable.Range. Is this code correct?

```
SurnameStartLetterList = new List<char>();
Enumerable.Range(65, 26).ToList().ForEach(character => SurnameStartLetterList.Add((char)character));
```

Or is there a better way to make this type of list?

Comment: `new List<char> { 'A', 'B', ... 'Z' }` I'll shut up now.

Comment: But I should say this: shouldn't your `Range()` be `Range(65, 26)`? The second parameter isn't the end number, it's the length of the range.

Comment: You are correct. I noticed and corrected it immediately.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Well, `string` is `IEnumerable<char>`, so this would also work:

```
"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".ToList()
```

You have to weigh the pros and cons on this.

Pros:

- Easier to read the above code than your loop (subjective, this was my opinion)
- Shorter code (but probably not enough to account for much)

Cons:

- Harder to read if you don't know what `.ToList()` will do with a string
- Can introduce bugs, for instance, would you easily spot the mistake here:

  ```
  "ABCDEFGHIJKLMN0PQRSTUVWXYZ".ToList()
  ```

  By easily I mean that you would spot the mistake as you're just reading past the code, not if you knew there was a problem here and went hunting for it.

Comment: Hahah! I made the mistake of copying the second version you posted (with the number `0`). I'm very glad I caught it immediately before I started pulling my hair out!

Comment: And if your purpose could make do with an `IList<char>` instead of a `List<char>` you could just use `"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"` directly.

Comment: Ah, the problems of "magic" strings.  Perhaps a loop with a comment?

Answer (score 51):

Maybe like this?

```
var surnameList = Enumerable.Range('A', 'Z' - 'A' + 1).
                     Select(c => (char)c).ToList();
```

Comment: I **really** like that solution, my initial reaction was *no way, that can't be done like that*, but sure enough.

Comment: Like.. return all capital letters in Norwegian :)

Comment: Ah, that's an entirely different problem :) I tried just looping through all 65536 character values, identifying uppercase characters in the Letter category, ended up with 937 character. Think that's a few more than the Norwegian alphabet. `Enumerable.Range(0, 65536).Select(c => (char)c).Where(c => char.IsLetter(c)).Where(c => char.IsUpper(c))`

Comment: Unicode goes to more than 65536 though, 109384 to be exact in unicode 6. The address space is 32-bit. .NET doesn't seem to provide any means to return all letters of a language though, so not sure how this would be achieved.

Answer (score 6):

I took Can's answer and made an extension function:

```
public static IEnumerable<char> Range(char start, char end)
{
  return Enumerable.Range((int)start, (int)end - (int)start + 1).Select(i => (char)i);
}
```

Usage:

```
Console.WriteLine(Range('a', 'f').Contains("Vive La France!"[6]));
```

Comment: This isn't an extension method, if that's what you meant to write. It's just a static method.