# Get an array of all alpha characters

Tags: c#, .net, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A to Z list of char from Enumerable.Range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5693854/a-to-z-list-of-char-from-enumerable-range)

Is there an easy way to get a `char[]` of all alpha characters?

I know I could do something like this:

```
char[] alphas = new char[]{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', ..............};
```

For all upper and lower case chars, but I am wondering if there is an easier (and cleaner looking) way to do this.

Comment: The first question here is "What do you need this for?", since there might be a simpler solution than using this char array...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14592478/922198

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
string alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
char [] alphas = (alphabet + alphabet.ToLower()).ToCharArray();
```

Answer (score 6):

```
Enumerable.Range((Int32)'A', 2 * 26).Select(c => (Char)c).ToArray();
```

Uppps, does not work - there are some non-letters between Z and a.

```
Enumerable.Range((Int32)'A', 26)
          .SelectMany(c => new [] { (Char)c, (Char)(c + 'a' - 'A' })
          .ToArray();
```

This solves the problem of the first attempt, but that is not really cleaner. Also note that this approach will interleave uppercase and lowercase letters. I would probably stick with the following solution.

```
"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".ToArray()
```

Or even better try to avoid this array in the first place. Maybe [`Char.IsLetter()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yyxz6h5w.aspx) might be useful. Or regular expressions.

Comment: he said he need For all upper and lower case chars

Comment: Just recognized my error.

Comment: [27] 92 '\\' char
  [28] 93 ']' char
  [29] 94 '^' char
  [30] 95 '_' char
  [31] 96 '`' char

Answer (score 6):

How "clean" is this:

```
char[] alphas = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".ToArray();
```

What about non-english characters?

Answer (score 4):

```
        char[] upperChars = Enumerable.Range(65, 26).Select(c => (Char)c).ToArray();
        char[] lowerChars = Enumerable.Range(97, 26).Select(c => (Char)c).ToArray();
        char[] allChars =
            (Enumerable.Range(65, 26).Select(c => (Char) c)
            .Union(Enumerable.Range(97, 26).Select(c => (Char) c)))
            .ToArray();
```

Comment: `Union(x)` is equivalent to `Concat(x).Distinct()`which could break if your locale does strange things.  `Concat` is better, imho, and also better expresses what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

you are converting ascii value of i to char value.
 65 is ascii value of 'A' and 90 of "Z"
 97 = "a" 122 = "z"

```
char [] chars = new char[52]
    for(int i=65;i<=90;i++)
     char[i-65]= ConvertToChar(i);

    for(int i=97,j=26;i<=122;i++,j++)
       char[j]= ConvertToChar(i);
```