# For loop when the values of the loop variable is a string of the pattern LetterNumberNumber?

Tags: c#, loops

I know to use for loops when loop variable is integer. I strongly needed to make a for loop where loop variable will take the values A00, A01, ..., A99, B00, B01, B99, ..., Z99. Are we allowed to use mixed patterns as the values of loop variables in C#?

How can we increment the loop variable in such a situation? Draft of what I wanted to do:
    *for (string i = A00, A01, ...,Z99; ???; ???)

{...}*

If we are not allowed to use such values as the loop variable, what can be done to handle the situation?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And the inevitable LINQ variant - you can generate a sequence of letters and numbers using LINQ and Enumerable.Range, eg:

```
var maxLetters=3;
var maxNumbers=3;

var values=from char c in Enumerable.Range('A',maxLetters).Select(c=>(char)c)
           from int i in Enumerable.Range(1,maxNumbers)
           select String.Format("{0}{1:d2}",(char)c,i);

foreach(var value in values)
{
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}

--------
A01
A02
A03
B01
B02
B03
C01
C02
C03
D01
D02
D03
```

Characters are equivalent to integers in C#, which means you can use Enumerable.Range to generate a sequence of increasing integers. Enumerable.Range will return integers though, which is why the cast back to `char` is required.

You can also specify the number or letters to use by subtracting the starting letter from the end letter, as shown in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5693854/a-to-z-list-of-char-from-enumerable-range):

```
var maxLetters = 'D' - 'A' +1;
```

Once you have the sequence of indices, you can iterate over it with `foreach`.

Comment: Many thanks. I successfully embedded your solution to my work. It worked nicely. I put maxLetters=26; maxNumbers=99 in my project. I noticed that the code you supplied misses 00s (A00, B00,...,Z00), but this not affected my work since later on I noticed that the thing I wanna decrypt also excludes them. Once again, thx a lot.

Answer (score 5):

You can have two imbricated loops that yield return your string.

for instance:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetLabels()
{
    for (char l = 'a'; l < 'z'; l++)
    {
        for (int d = 0; d < 99; d++)
        {
            yield return string.Format("{0}{1:D2}", l, d);
        }
    }    
}
```

**Note**: the yield return allows you to have an enumerable without having to build the whole combination at once. If used in a Linq query, or in a foreach loop, the values will be built just before they are needed.

Comment: I am trying to understand/confirm your solution. "yield" is new to me. I wanted to do (when user clicked a button) A00,....,Z99 to be a value in a TextBox in a windows form that will change automatically by itself (without the need of manual entring) while I am checking the value of a bool variable: situation == function(parameter1, ..., parameter5,...). parameter5 will take values A00,...,Z99, and I'll do some job based on the value of the variable situation. Definitely, TextBox may not be needed. TextBox is just for, in later stage, to restrict the scope of scanning.

Comment: @ErdoganCEVHER what you describe isn't a loop at all.

Comment: more info on yield return / yield break: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I guessed that. But, I wanted to do it that way since the answer to this question may reveal a general handling of the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can construct the list using a double loop:

```
for (char c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; c++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        string s = $"{c}{i:d2}";
    }
}
```

Since `A00` can impossibly be an `int`, why not make it a string and iterate over it using `foreach`? You can use `yield` to ease the iteration and prevent creating an endless list

```
foreach (string s in listOfPossibilities)
{ }
```

Depending on your logic of constructing the `A00...Z99` you can also construct the string out of an integer if possible. You would need some conversion to do yourself.

```
for (int i = 0;;)
{
    string s = ConvertIntergerToSpecial(i);
}
```

Comment: This'll be fun with 2600 entries.

Answer (score 0):

Loop variables can only be one type, you could use `Int.Parse()` in combination with substring or RegEx:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

Code:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"[A-Z]");
Match match = regex.Match("A00");
// match is now A
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\d+");
Match match = regex.Match("A00");
// match is now 00
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the other answers posted here for the question, particularly the LINQ method. Here is a single loop way of doing it, just a layman's programming stuff,

```
            String result = "";
            char c =  'A';
            String v = "";
            for (int i = 0; v != "Z99"; i++)    // Loop until you reach Z99
            {
                v = String.Format("{0}{1:D2}", c, i); // A00,A001.... Z99
                if (i == 99) { i = 0; c++; }  // Reset counter and increment character
                result += v +" "; // Just to display the result
            }
            MessageBox.Show(result);
```