# How to instruct irregular course in Enumerable in C#?

Tags: c#, enumerable

Panagiotis Kanavos introduced the following clever solution to produce LetterNumberNumber pattern in this SOF question: [For loop when the values of the loop variable is a string of the pattern LetterNumberNumber?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32906616/for-loop-when-the-values-of-the-loop-variable-is-a-string-of-the-pattern-lettern)

```
var maxLetters=3; // Take 26 for all letters    
var maxNumbers=3; // Take 99 for all the required numbers   

var values=from char c in Enumerable.Range('A',maxLetters).Select(c=>(char)c)    
       from int i in Enumerable.Range(1,maxNumbers)    
       select String.Format("{0}{1:d2}",(char)c,i);    

foreach(var value in values)    
{    
    Console.WriteLine(value);    
}
```

---

A01
A02
A03
B01
B02
B03
C01
C02
C03
D01
D02
D03

Is there way to instruct irregular course in Enumerable stuff? "Enumerable.Range(1, maxNumbers)" leads 01, 02, ...,99 (for maxNumbers 99).

Restriction Examples:
1. Restrict (01,02,...,99) only to (01,03,05,07,09,11,13)
2. Restrict (01,02,...,99) only to (02,04,06,08,10)
3. Restrict (01,02,...,99) only to (01,04,09,10)

**What I did:**
I worked "Enumarable", tried its methods like: Enumerable.Contains(1,3,5,7,9,13) gave big error, and I could not achieve to reach:
A01, A03, A05, ....,Z09, Z11, Z13.

If Enumarable is not suitable for this type of job, what do you offer to handle the problem?

Comment: Use the range to index into an array containing the values you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a direct feature in C#, while it is in F#.

F# example:

```
[1..2..10]
```

will produce a list of [1,3,5,7,9].

You first example,  "Restrict (01,02,...,99) only to (01,03,05,07,09,11,13)" can be achieved with

```
Enumerable.Range(1,99).Where(x => x % 2 == 1).Take(7);
```

The second example, "Restrict (01,02,...,99) only to (02,04,06,08,10)" can be achieved with

```
Enumerable.Range(1,99).Where(x => x % 2 == 0).Take(5);
```

And your third example, "Restrict (01,02,...,99) only to (01,04,09,10)" seems odd. I'm not sure what the pattern here is. If the last element isn't a typo, then starting at one and incrementing by 3, then 5, then 1 seems unclear, but here's a method that can accomplish it.

```
public static IEnumerable<int> GetOddMutation(int start, int max, int count, List<int> increments) {
    int counter = 0;
    int reset = increments.Count - 1;
    int index = 0;
    int incremented = start;
    while(counter < count) {
        var previous = incremented;
        incremented += increments[index];
        index = index == reset ? 0 : index + 1;
        counter++;
        if(previous != incremented) //Avoid duplicates if 0 is part of the incrementation strategy. Alternatively, call .Distinct() on the method.
        yield return incremented;
    }
}
```

called with

```
GetOddMutation(1,99,4, new List<int> {0,3,5,1})
```

will result in [1,4,9,10]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your very informative, detailed and very explanatory answer. I tried and it solved. Many thx again.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you want the `Enumerable.Range(1, maxNumbers)` to be restricted by a certain condition rather than having all of the integers. Since `Enumerable.Range()` produces an `IEnumerable<int>`, you can chain any LINQ filtering method calls, namely the `Enumerable.Where()` method. For example, `Enumerable.Range(1, 99).Where(x => x % 3 == 0)` would yield (3,6,9,...99).

If you only wanted the specific case you specified where  the list only contains (1,3,5,7,9,13), you could simply make a list with the desired numbers: `new List<int> {1,3,5,7,9,13}`; you could also use `Enumerable.Range(1, maxNumbers).Where(x => x % 2 == 1)` and `maxNumbers = 13`.